# What is SpriteStudio?

Tags: 2d, animation, stride

In the game, I've seen asset types for animations that are of SpriteStudio.
I have searched the documentation and cannot find any information on what this is.

I looked at the template project that purportedly covers SpriteStudio, but I don't see anything that really explains how to use it. There are various entities of type "SpriteStudio" that reference assets called SpriteStudio Animations. These assets show their source to be files with a ".ssae" extension. I assume these entities, assets, and resources are purposed to create the 2D animations within the demo.

I don't see how to generate ".ssae" files, nor is there any editor that I could find for the SpriteStudio Animation assets.

Is SpriteStudio separate software? Is it a sub-editor of the Game Studio? How do I create ".ssae" files?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the file? Where did you find it? What do you assume is its content and how did you come to that conclusion? How did you find out that there is a program named "Sprite Studio" which might be able to open these files?

Comment: I  reworded the question to try to make my assumptions clearer.

Comment: I'd suspect these files might be where the engine stores the metadata like individual sprite regions and pivots within a sprite sheet when [marked up with the sprite editor](http://doc.xenko.com/latest/en/manual/sprites/edit-sprites.html). Can you try setting up a new sprite sheet this way and verify what new files are created as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpriteStudio is an external software for 2d animation that Xenko supports back, I believe when it's own by Silicon Studio (I think it does make sense since Xenko is originally a Japanese game engine, and SpriteStudio is of Japan, too).
I also know that fact from the documentation site, but can't find it anymore now (maybe Stride won't support it anymore?).

[You can see the website here](https://www.webtech.co.jp/eng/spritestudio/)